# Handling batches of Commands

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have an architecture like the one described in [this blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-command-side-of-my-architecture/). In summary, I have command objects, e.g. :

```
public class MoveCustomerCommand : ICommand
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Address NewAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And command handlers for each command which derive from the interface `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class MoveCustomerCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>
{
    public void Handle(MoveCustomerCommand command)
    {
        // Logic here
    }
}
```

Now I'm looking for a clean solution to the following use case: Some clients produce a batch of heterogenous commands that need to be processed. In other words, I want to implement the following:

```
void HandleBatch(List<ICommand> batch) {
}
```

I have some ideas but I'm not convinced that any of them is good enough.

**Option 1** Put a humongous switch-case in the `HandleBatch` function.

```cs
void HandleBatch(List<ICommand> batch) {
  foreach (var command in batch) {
    switch (command) {
      case MoveCustomerCommand cmd:
        new MoveCustomerCommandHandler().Handle(cmd);
        break;
      case DeleteCustomerCommand cmd:
        new DeleteCustomerCommandHandler().Handle(cmd);
        break;
      // ....
    }

  }
}
```

**Option 2** Use reflections to find the appropriate command handler for each command.

```cs
void HandleBatch(List<ICommand> batch) {
  foreach (var command in batch) {
    var commandType = command.GetType();

    var handlerInterface = typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
      .MakeGenericType(new Type[]{commandType});

    // Search the current assembly for a type that implements "handlerInterface" 
    var handlerType = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t != handlerInterface  &&
                    handlerInterface.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                ).First();

    var handler = CreateInstance(handlerType);
    handler.Handle(command);
  }
}
```

**Option 3** Same as option 2, but also annotate all the Handlers with a custom annotation and when searching for the type filter by annotation as well.

**Option 4** Something else?

Another inconvenience is that the `HandleBatch` will have to have handy an instance of virtually every possible dependency since most of the logic of the application is in these commands. But I guess I can't go around this.

Comment: My bad, all commands implement `ICommand` and `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` is such that `TCommand` implements `ICommand`. I updated the question.

Comment: Update: Added sample code in the question.

Comment: [Another](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2012/writing-highly-maintainable-wcf-services/) of Steven's blog posts has what you are looking for (see `CommandService`)

Comment: I've dealt with this situation in the past using what I would call `CommandTable`. This is reasonably scalable compared to the reflection mechanism, but does not have the same overhead as reflection. Needless to say, the `switch case` mechanism is not the most maintainable

Comment: @Vikhram can you give more information about this `CommandTable`? Is it just a dictionary of `ICommand` to `ICommandHandler` or smth more clever? Also, what is the overhead of the reflections?

Comment: While the linked blog post shows an excellent example of the Decorator Pattern, it shows nothing near the Command Pattern. By reducing commands to, "_simple data containers without behavior_," it violates the purpose of a command, which, "_declares an interface for executing an operation._" A data structure is neither an interface nor an operation. Using this new pattern is fine; but calling it a Command Pattern is wishful thinking by its author and quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Suppose you have the following commands:

```
public class MoveCustomerCommand : ICommand
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

        public void Execute(object parameter) { }


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }

public class KillCustomerCommand : ICommand
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

        public void Execute(object parameter) { }


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Now consider the following architecture proposal for the handlers:

```
 public abstract class CommandHandlerBase
    {
        protected static readonly Dictionary<Type, CommandHandlerBase> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, CommandHandlerBase>();

        protected abstract void HandleCommand<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand: ICommand;

        public static void Handle<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
        {
            if (_handlers.TryGetValue(typeof(TCommand), out var handler))
            {
                handler.HandleCommand(command);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class CommandHandlerBase<TCommandHandlerBase, TCommand> : CommandHandlerBase
        where TCommandHandlerBase : CommandHandlerBase<TCommandHandlerBase, TCommand>, new() where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var type = typeof(TCommand);
            _handlers[type] = new TCommandHandlerBase();
        }

        protected override void HandleCommand<T>(T command) => Handle((TCommand) (object) command);

        public abstract void Handle(TCommand command);
    }
```

Basically what we do is to centralize all the handling into one base class, and we provide just an entry point for handling any `TCommand` (provided that there is a handler registered, you can put a default case or just crash if no handler is found).

The implementation may look confusing at first sight, but the usage is really nice after: we only define our handlers classes and we call `Register`. Let's see how they look:

```
public class MoveCustomerCommandHandler : CommandHandlerBase<MoveCustomerCommandHandler, MoveCustomerCommand>
    {
        public override void Handle(MoveCustomerCommand command) => Console.WriteLine("Moving the customer");
    }

    public class KillCustomerCommandHandler : CommandHandlerBase<KillCustomerCommandHandler, KillCustomerCommand>
    {
        public override void Handle(KillCustomerCommand command) => Console.WriteLine("Killing the customer");
    }
```

And testing:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MoveCustomerCommandHandler.Register();
    KillCustomerCommandHandler.Register();
    CommandHandlerBase.Handle(new MoveCustomerCommand());
    CommandHandlerBase.Handle(new KillCustomerCommand());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I think this approach is more maintainable and scalable, no need for reflection (with its performance hit), no need for very big switchs statements or hardcoded solutions.

Furthermore, you can add later an unregister method, or to keep more than one handler for a given command, the limit is the sky.. =)